# Recommendations for Deploying a Simple Node.js Web Server

Tags: node.js

Hello I want to deploy a simple NodeJS web server. The server is used to send an email given the email details from the client side. I've tested it on localhost and everything works. I just needed some help on figuring the next step which is to deploy the application. I am looking for tools which can provide me with a URL for my project so I can access my app anytime using this URL. What software tool would you recommend me to use? Any suggestions are highly appreciated.

Comment: You can deploy it in `VPS`, `Shared Hosting`, `Netlify`, `AWS`, `Google Cloud`.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend [Vercel](https://vercel.com/), it is very simple to use and convenient for deployment.

I tried it for my own blog and done the deployment within 10 minutes. You just need to login with GitHub and then grant Vercel access to the repository that you want to deploy.